# Let $(G,\cdot)$ be a finite abelian group and $m\in\Bbb{N}$. Prove that $S=\{g\in G\mid(o(g),m)=1\}\le G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

I am aware that I need to show that given any $g_1,g_2$ in $S$ if $(o(g_1g_2^{-1}),m)=1$ then $S$ will be a subgroup of $G$.

Now let $o(g_1)=r,o(g_2)=s,o(g_1g_2^{-1})=t$. Since $G$ is abelian we have

$$\begin{align}
(g_1g_2^{-1})^{rs}&=g_1^{rs}(g_2^{-1})^{rs}\\
&=(g_1^r)^s((g_2^s)^{-1})^r\\
&=e^s(e^{-1})^r\\
&=e^se^r.
\end{align}$$

This implies that $t\mid rs$. Now we must show that $(t,m)=1$. I could not find a way to show this.

Any help here will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: $(t,m)=1$ follows immediately from the fact that $(rs,m)=1$.

Comment: @Servaes Please confirm if what follows is what you mean. if $(rs,m)=1$ then we have $(rs)x+(m)y=1$. Also since $t\vert rs$ we have $rs=qt$ for some $q$. Now $(rs)x+(m)y=(qt)x+(m)y=(t)qx+(m)y=1$ which means that $(t,m)=1$

Comment: That is indeed what I mean.

Comment: @Servaes Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Put more simply; any common divisor of $t$ and $m$ is also a common divisor of $rs$ and $m$.

Answer (score 0):

If $g,h\in S$, if $a=o(g)$ and $b=o(h)$, then $o(h^{-1})=b$ and (since $G$ is abelian)$$o(gh^{-1})\mid o(g)o(h^{-1})=ab.$$Since both $a$ and $b$ are coprime with $m$, then so is $ab$ and therefore then so is $o(gh^{-1})$. In fact, if $o(gh^{-1})$ and $m$ are *not* coprime, then there is a prime number $p$ such that $p\mid o(gh^{-1})$ and $p\mid m$. But$$p\mid o(gh^{-1})\implies p\mid ab\implies p\mid a\text{ or }p\mid b.$$But this is impossible, since $(a,m)=(b,m)=1$.

Comment: It is not true that $o(gh)=o(g)o(h)$.

Comment: @Servaes Right. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Great. But the last sentence is precisely what OP asks to show; the rest of what you wrote is already shown in the question.

Comment: @Servaes Right (again!). I have completed the proof.

Comment: Another proof of the central fact: if $xa + ym = 1$ and $x'b + y'm = 1$ (where $x,x',y,y'$ exist by Bezout's identity), then $(xx')(ab) + (xay'+x'by+yy')m = (xa+ym)(x'b+y'm) = 1$.  So any common divisor of $ab$ and $m$ also divides 1.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos you wrote "But this is impossible, since $(a,m)=(b,m)=1$". i did not get why $(a,m)=(b,m)=1$ implies the negation of $(p\vert a$ or $p\vert b)$. Please help with this.

Answer (score 0):

More generally let $M$ be a set of naturals closed under multiplication and divisors, and let $S$ be the elements of $G$ whose order lies in $M$.  If $\,g,h\in S$ then $\,g^j = 1 = h^k\,$ for $\,j,k\in M$ so $\,jk\in M\,$ and $\,(gh)^{jk} = (g^j)^k (h^k)^j = 1\,$ so $\,o(gh)\mid jk\,$ so $\,gh\in S,\,$ and $\,(g^{-1})^j = (g^j)^{-1} = 1\,$ so $\,g^{-1}\in S$

**Remark** $ $ OP is special case $\,M=$ all naturals coprime to $m,\,$ which is closed under multiplication and divisors by Euclid [said equivalently: units (= invertibles) $\!\bmod m\,$ enjoy such closure].

Comment: Such an $M$ is known as a *saturated monoid*.

Comment: Hmm, to me the definition of saturated monoid is: $N$ is a saturated submonoid of $M$ if whenever $nx \in N$ for $n > 0, x \in M$, then $x \in N$.  And a commutative cancellative monoid $M$ is saturated if it's a saturated submonoid of $M^{gp}$.  (So for example, $\{ 0, 2, 3, 4, \ldots \}$ is not saturated because $2 (3 - 2) = 2$ is in the monoid but $3 - 2$ is not; on the other hand, $\{ 0, 2, 4, 6, \ldots \}$ is saturated.)

Comment: @Daniel Where did you encounter that nonstandard definition? In commutative algebra a monoid $M$ (multiplicatively closed set with $1)$ is called *saturated* if it is *closed under divisors*. Thus $M$ is a saturated monoid precisely when it satifies $\,ab\in M\iff a,b\in M,\,$ e.g. see [Wikipedia.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicatively_closed_set)

Comment: In my study of monoid theory, that condition for a submonoid $N$ of $M$ was called "$N$ is a face of $M$".  (These terms came from study related to logarithmic geometry where as a part of it, we studied schemes $\operatorname{Spec} k[M]$ for monoids $M$, so the "faces" of $M$ roughly corresponded to the faces of that cone, and the "saturated" condition roughly corresponded to a nonsingular condition.)

Comment: @Daniel Your notion of "saturated" is commonly called "root-closed" in multiplicative contexts,  i.e. $M\subset K$ is root-closed in $K$ if $\,x\in K,\, n\in\Bbb N,\,x^n\in M\,\Rightarrow\,x\in M\ \ \ $